# Issue setting UIImageView from local image in documents directory

Tags: swift, realm, nsurl, sdwebimage, nsdocumentdirectory

I am trying to load images that I have downloaded using Alamofire to the documents directory. I store the filenames in a Realm database. Once it is time to display the image I take the path to the documents directory and append the filename. This path doesn't seem to work for building a UIImage though.

```
if let name = playlist.RLMsongs[indexPath.row].name, let imageURL = playlist.RLMsongs[indexPath.row].album?.image?.getImageURL(.SmallImage), let fileName = playlist.RLMsongs[indexPath.row].album?.image?.smallLocalFileName {
    cell.songName.text = name

    let range = imageURL.rangeOfString("http")
    if let theRange = range where theRange.startIndex == imageURL.startIndex { // imageURL starts with "http" (remote url)
        cell.albumImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imageURL), placeholderImage: UIColor.imageFromColor(UIColor.grayColor())) {
            _ in
            cell.albumImage.fadeIn(completion: nil)
        }
    } else {
        cell.albumImage.image = UIImage(named: fileName) // images still do not load
        // tried this first -> cell.albumImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: imageURL), placeholderImage: UIColor.imageFromColor(UIColor.grayColor()))
    }
}
```

Here is the bit that builds the path (imageURL above):

```
let documentsDir = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
let path = documentsDir.URLByAppendingPathComponent(localFile).path
return path
```

As per TiM's recommendation I checked the value of imageURL on a breakpoint and it looks just fine:

```
imageURL: "/Users/danielnall/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0B8D64B5-9593-4F86-BBD3-E408682C5C0F/data/Containers/Data/Application/011E4805-40EB-4221-9D7D-1C1D64660186/Documents/75.9226ecd6893cb01a306c974d9d8ffd62803109c1.png"
```

This is the full path on the simulator and is only missing the file schema (file://) which for the use of NSURL fileURLWithPath should be just fine I think.

Comment: Can you please not just post micro-snippets of code. Post the functions, and classes so we can see how it all works. Also, when you have functions like `sd_setImageWithURL`, I would be interested in seeing how it works and not have to guess what it does.

Comment: This seems to imply there's a problem with the way you're constructing your file paths. I'd recommend going through with breakpoints and checking the actual value of `imageURL` before to make sure they match up to what you're expecting.

Comment: @ryantxr the sd_setImageWithURL is a function from the library sdwebimage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution to the problem which was unrelated to the direction of this question. Turned out that the issue was in my override of the prepareForReuse method in my UITableViewCell class. Thank you for everyone's suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the PNG file in Documents then all you need to do is this.

(Assuming that cell.albumImage is UIImageView)

```
let imageFileName = "75.9226ecd6893cb01a306c974d9d8ffd62803109c1.png"
cell.albumImage.image = UIImage(named: imageFileName)
```

Check if file exists:

```
func fileExists(filePath: String) -> Bool {
    let filemanager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if filemanager.fileExistsAtPath(filePath) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Tried this and the images still do not load. See above edit in question.

Comment: Check to see if the file exists.

Comment: Yea I checked and the file does exist. I have even navigated to the image in Finder and have verified that the image has data and is not corrupted or anything.